# Tiny Death Star: I'm not getting Supply Officers and VIPs. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

... that's why I'm hesitant to build more Imperial floors because it raises my chance sending Bitizens to empty floors and wasting them.

Follow-up question: What are Imperial floors for?  So far, the rewards for building them and completing missions seem small (1500-2000 coins) compared to the continuous income of Food, Service, Recreation and Retail floors.  Plus, as I said, I'm not getting supply officers.

(I've only built 10 levels.)

Comment: VIPs are pretty random from what I've seen. I got a string of 3-4 within a span of ten minutes the other day, and then none for quite some time.

Answer (score 3):

1. As far as I can tell, the VIPs are indeed random, with perhaps a slightly higher chance to yield Supply Officers. Unfortunately, they'll only show up when you're actively playing, so it might require more real time invested than you're willing to, and there's never a guarantee that any particular one will show up.
2. Imperial floor missions start small, but soon become hugely rewarding; the one I'm currently working on gives a reward of 50k, and previous ones have been in the 75-80k range. However, there's not much point in building Imperial levels until the mission asks you to, and it can be frustrating if you're asked for a specific one but the levels you build turn out differently several times in a row. In that case, it can be worth skipping a mission for a few Bux and getting something you're better equipped for.

Comment: Alex, just asking: do or don't you think you'd have earned the 50k more easily via imperial floors instead of via regular floors?  By the way, today it's asking me to build a 30k floor to complete a 3k mission.  I spent 20k for a 2k reward yesterday and I feel scammed.

Comment: The rewards get better with time.  Eventually you will recoup at least half of the cost of the floor by completing the quests.  Yes, it is easier to passively earn the money on the regular floors, but then you are missing out on the Star Wars theme.  Building the Imperial levels allows you the opportunity to unlock 10 separate cut scenes.

Comment: @William, I agree with David. I guess it all depends on your ultimate goal in playing the game, but you've gotta build the Imperial Levels anyway to unlock everything. And the Supply Officers come frequently enough that you could just never pay for them, and the Levels will eventually pay for themselves... theoretically. At the moment there's only a finite number of Vader quests, but presumably in the future there will be more, and they will more and more rely on levels you already have rather than requiring you to build more.

Answer (score 0):

At later levels (10+ Imperial Floors), the rewards for completing Darth Vader's quests are in the 100k+ range, so Imperial floors are perhaps the most lucrative.  To prove the point, a level 6 commercial floor with three 9 stars will generate 50k+ when all items are stocked (which can take 6+ hours, but is fairly passive).  By building up the Imperial resources at every chance (at least ten of each one), you can reduce the amount of time needed to complete Vader's quests.

Regarding VIPs, make sure you haven't saved too many.  Once you have five saved VIPs, you will reduce the likelihood of getting more; especially of the type you have saved.  It's almost like the game doesn't like you having so many saved.  I had an Upgrader VIP I was saving for the Emperor, and I didn't see another Upgrader for five days straight(until I used my saved Upgrader).  If you use them, they will be replenished.  If you save them, it appears the chance you will get more diminishes.

Comment: There is no evidence that saving VIPs reduces the appearance of different types.  In fact, I've had all the slots filled with the same type at various times.

Comment: My apologies, I was just going from personal experience.  Unless you mean you had a supply officer in every slot...I've had that before.  I should have specified the Upgrader VIP, the Recruiting Officer VIP, and the Worker VIP.  If I had one of any of these types, I have found (in my own personal game) that I would not get an additional VIP of the same type.